# Trying to use Yesod.Form.Richtext in a scaffolded site, I am unable to compile due to an issue in Summernote.hs

Tags: haskell, yesod, rich-text-editor, summernote

I am setting up a blog/website using Yesod. I followed a couple of the tutorials currently available. I am definitely interested in having an HTML editor available to post articles. When I set up NicEditor in the development server, it worked well enough, however when I moved it to an Nginx proxy server, it no longer worked. I had a feeling the issue was a CORS issue, but I enable CORS on the Yesod side and on the Nginx side and it still does not work.

Then someone told me about Yesod.Forms.Richtext and Summernote. When I included Summernote in my extra-deps and package.yaml files, my web app no longer could compile. I tried editing the Yesod.Forms.Richtext package myself to get it to compile, but I could not get it to work. When I try to compile, I am given the following error message:

```
yesod-form-richtext>     * Could not deduce (Monad m0)
yesod-form-richtext>       from the context: (YesodSummernote site, Monad m)
yesod-form-richtext>         bound by the type signature for:
yesod-form-richtext>                    snHtmlField :: forall site (m :: * -> *).
yesod-form-richtext>                                   (YesodSummernote site, Monad m) =>
yesod-form-richtext>                                   Field (HandlerT site m) Html
yesod-form-richtext>         at src/Yesod/Form/Summernote.hs:(102,16)-(103,43)
yesod-form-richtext>       The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
yesod-form-richtext>     * In the ambiguity check for `snHtmlField'
yesod-form-richtext>       To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
yesod-form-richtext>       In the type signature:
yesod-form-richtext>         snHtmlField :: (YesodSummernote site, Monad m) =>
yesod-form-richtext>                        Field (HandlerT site m) Html
yesod-form-richtext>     |
yesod-form-richtext> 102 | snHtmlField :: (YesodSummernote site, Monad m)
yesod-form-richtext>     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

One thing I tried to do is modify the code to include the {-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes -#} pragma, but it did not help. Is this something that is common with this library? Is there an easier to use Html editor with Yesod?

Comment: It turns out that with Yesod 1.5, a change was made to a package provided by Yesod implementing MonadUnliftIO. This was announced in a [Yesod blog post](https://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2018/01/upcoming-yesod-breaking-changes). This change affects the yesod-form-richtext package which makes it impossible to compile with Yesod 1.6. The alternatives at the moment are to manually include an Html editor or use the old Yesod.Form.Nic or to base the project on Yesod 1.4 which makes using the official, up to date, stack scaffolds impossible to use.